# Two toned smoke?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to get smoke to start out red and end black, but have found no possible way to have smoke colors change over time.  Can anyone help me with this?  I've gotten close here, but as you can see, the render has a black outline around the highlight areas...(the hotter areas).I realize I could change to a fire simulation, but that's not what I'm after. [image]

Comment: Are you using source particles?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the attribute heat like this:

[image]